# Why doesn't my expires headers make my files stay in cache?

Tags: firefox, caching

I'm using valid expires and no-cache headers for my static files and they stay cached for as long as I keep browsing, but when I close my browser and use it back after a while I see the static files loading again, even when not refreshing with ctrl (+ shift) + r

I'm using Firefox, cache size set to 250MB and I don't let it remove any private or cached data.

> Headers:
>   Accept-Ranges: bytes
>   Cache-Control: max-age=29030400, public
>   Content-Length: 142061
>   Content-Type: image/png
>   Date: Tue, 08 Dec 2009 19:18:43 GMT
>   Expires: Tue, 09 Nov 2010 19:18:43 GMT
>   Last-Modified: Sun, 18 Jan 2009 18:33:48 GMT
>   Server: Apache/2.2.14 (EL)

Comment: You're using a "co-cache" header? What's that? Without actually seeing the header traffic, in both directions, it's hard to understand your question.

Comment: Can you post what your header assignments look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Firefox?  Is the server sending Etags for the static files?  You can view details about Firefox cache by going to the address *about:cache* and poking around.  That will give you an idea of what Firefox is caching.

Update: After looking at your header tags, it seems as if the *max-age* value is set to a date that is way in the past and that is overriding the the value being set in the *Expires* header.  See the HTTP 1.1 protocol definition at: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3.

> If a response includes both an Expires
>   header and a max-age directive, the
>   max-age directive overrides the
>   Expires header, even if the Expires
>   header is more restrictive. This rule
>   allows an origin server to provide,
>   for a given response, a longer
>   expiration time to an HTTP/1.1 (or
>   later) cache than to an HTTP/1.0
>   cache. This might be useful if certain
>   HTTP/1.0 caches improperly calculate
>   ages or expiration times, perhaps due
>   to desynchronized clocks.

You will have to modify your *Cache-Control* header being sent by the server.

Comment: When looking at the about:cache you will be able to see what headers firefox is storing.

Comment: Always the latest one, at this time 3.5.5. And no etags are disabled.